# Using conditionals in Logstash pipeline configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I am trying to use Logstash conditionals in a context of pipeline output configuration. 
Based on the presence of `device` field in the payload I'd like to forward the event to the appropriate index name in Elasticsearch:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["10.1.1.5:9200"]
        if [device] ~= \.* {
          index => "%{[device][0]}-%{+YYYY.ww}"
        } else {
          index => "%{[beat][name]}-%{+YYYY.ww}"
        }
    }
}
```

The above code would fail with the following mgs in the log indicating the syntax error:

```
...
"Expected one of #, => at line 14, column 12 (byte 326) after output {\n    elasticsearch {\n        hosts => [\"10.1.1.5:9200\"]\n        if "
...
```

Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [conditional](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html) before the elasticsearch output, not inside it.

```
output {
    if [device] ~= \.* {  
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["10.1.1.5:9200"]
            index => "%{[device][0]}-%{+YYYY.ww}"
        }
    } else {  
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["10.1.1.5:9200"]
            index => "%{[beat][name]}-%{+YYYY.ww}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My pipeline config looks like this: `bash-4.2$ cat /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/output_main
output {
  if [device] ~= \.* {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["es-host:9200"]
      index => "%{[device][0]}-%{+YYYY.ww}"
    }
  } else {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["es-host:9200"]
      index => "%{[beat][name]}-%{+YYYY.ww}"
  }
}` still getting error: `"Expected one of #, in, not , ==, !=, <=, >=, <, >, =~, !~, and, or, xor, nand, { at line 12, column 15 (byte 253) after output {\n  if [device] "`

Comment: Update your question with your full current config, not just the output part, and check if your brackets are closing.